# How to autocomplete methods with resharper templates

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012, autocomplete, resharper

I have a resharper template like below

```
new Assembly().$Add$.View();
```

`Add` has been marked as `Execute Basic Completion` macro. Now when I expand the macro I get

```
new Assembly().Add.View();
```

with Add highlighted and the autocomplete popup raised. I then select the method I want to expand in here which can be one of a dozen methods starting with `Add` such as `AddLine` or `AddPointCloud` etc. However when I select the method the following happens.

```
new Assembly().AddLine();.View();
```

Note that `AddLine` is a method with a single argument. As well an extra semicolon has been injected into the template breaking the code. The desired finished line would be

```
new Assembly().AddLine(points).View();
```

where `points` is a variable declared previously and I would type it in during template expansion.

My question is, is it at all possible using resharper templates to trigger autocompletes on methods such as above with the method being in the middle of a call chain.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the template to

```
new Assembly()
    .$Add$($args$)
    .View();
```

where `args` is a `comma-delimited list of values` and it seems to now work